# Postgres update delta between

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is table in postgres db:

```
event_stats_table

id: pk int
rank: int
rank_delta: int
event_id: int
user_id: int
```

Every record saves user position for every event.

I am trying to write a query which would update `rank_delta` fields for all users in comparing with the previous event_id. If previous event_id is null - write 0.

Current and previous id are known, I do not need to update data between every event, only selected pair.

For example I need to update deltas between `event_id=1` and `event_id=2` and write data into `event_id=2` row and tried following sql:

```sql
update event_stats_table
set rank_delta = st1.rank - coalesce(st2.rank, st1.rank_delta)
from event_stats_table st1
    left outer join event_stats_table st2 on st1.user_id = st2.user_id and st2.event_id = 1
    where st1.event_id = 2;
```

But this event updates both records instead of `st1` only. I tried to put `st1` in the first line of sql and got syntax errors, because st1 is not known at that moment.

I appreciate any advises on this case or even better solutions which are no doubt exist, thx.

**UPD 1** changed `grand_prix_id` to `event_id` everywhere

**UPD 2** Adding sample datum:
Before:

| id | rank | rank_delta | event_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 1 |

After:

| id | rank | rank_delta | event_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | -4 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: May you please add sample data and expected result also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is something weird about handling such self joins in Postgres, but you can  do

```
CREATE TABLE event_stats_table(

id int,
points int,
rank int,
rank_delta int,
event_id int,
user_id int,
  grand_prix_id int)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO event_stats_table VALUES( 1,1,2,1,1,1,1), ( 1,1,1,1,2,1,2)
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 2
> ```

```
WITH st2 as (
   SELECT 
user_id as user_id2,
  rank as rank2,
  event_id as event_id2 FROM  event_stats_table)
update event_stats_table  st1
set rank_delta = rank - coalesce(st2.rank2, rank_delta)
from  st2 
  WHERE st1.user_id = st2.user_id2 and st2.event_id2 = 1
    AND  st1.event_id = 2;
```

> ```
> UPDATE 1
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM event_stats_table
```

| id | points | rank | rank_delta | event_id | user_id | grand_prix_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | -1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cqx4Qliy)

Comment: I accidentally wrote grand_prix_id instead of event_id in my sql script

Comment: that doesn't matter much  you need to exchange it in the quer see changed answer

Answer (score 0):

Where you're going wrong is that the table to updated is already available for referencing columns and is effectively joined to the tables listed in the `FROM` part of the statement. In your case the tables listed in your `FROM` don't change their results depending on which row of the table to be updated is being evaluated. See [the UPDATE syntax docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-update.html) for more information.

One way to address this would be something like:

```sql
update event_stats_table est
set rank_delta = st1.rank - coalesce(st2.rank, st1.rank_delta)
from event_stats_table st1
    left outer join event_stats_table st2 on st1.user_id = st2.user_id and st2.grand_prix_id = 1
    where st1.grand_prix_id = 2 and est.id = st1.id;
```

Comment: no this will result in an error https://dbfiddle.uk/Jpgd4Q7n like i said in myanswer, weird behaviour in postgres

Comment: Error confirmed, I got such error from the beginning, somehow postgres do not accept this syntax

Comment: The error was because you cannot use the table alias when listing columns for update in the set part of the statement (updated now in my answer). I think you are right that it is weird behavior from postgres; the weirdness is that there is an implied join between the table to be updated and the first table listed in FROM and you are not required to specify how the JOIN is to occur.

Comment: yes i know that is why you need to use my answer